# How to reorganize folder/file physical location on disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a WD Velociraptor disk that is 80% full. The thing with the Velociraptor disks is that they are blazing fast (for a spinning platter disk), but the speed decreases with the further out the data is on the disk. The thing is that I have some things that I want to read fast (Window/GTA V/Starcitizen) and other things that I don't care that much (Office/Visual Studio). The problem is that for historical reasons the many desired files are further outside and the less desired ones are inside.

I there a way to relocate files/folders on the disk by manually defined access priority?

(Yes I know, just buy an SDD and be done with it... I probably will some time soon for this system, but I was wondering if can do with what I have not for the time being.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piriform's [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) has an [option](http://www.piriform.com/docs/defraggler/defraggler-settings/defraggler-options-defrag-tab) you can use:

[image: 1]

Comment: Not a bad tool, but it appears to do the opposite of what I want. But it can be achieved this way, though with higher effort.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly control the physical file placement within a volume.  You can influence it, however.  The best way to do this would be to use a tool like GParted or something similar from a Linux boot CD to shrink the partition and then move it to the end of the disk.  That way you'll have free space at the beginning of the disk.  If you create a new partition in this free space, anything you store on it will be guaranteed to be near the front of the disk where you want it.

Historical fun fact:

The default for most Linux distros is to create a separate swap partition at the beginning of a drive for exactly this reason.  The swap file sees a lot of use and you want it to be fast and contiguous.